# how to inject custom window into windows explorer

Tags: windows, hook, explorer

RT.as the picture below.
[image: custom window inject into explorer]

I try several ways as below, but not work :

1. Explorer Bars, Tool Bands, and Desk Bands， see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144099(VS.85).aspx)
2. Namespace extensions，see [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7973/An-almost-complete-Namespace-Extension-Sample)
3. Implementing a Folder View， see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144092(v=vs.85).aspx)

I have resolve this problem, just resize the folder view window and create a new custom window and move it to the right postion, show below, this code will show custom window in top of folder view window:

```
HWND phwnd = (HWND)explorer SHELLDLL_DefView handle;
HWND chwnd = (HWND)explorer DirectUIHWND handle;
RECT *rcClient = new RECT(); 
GetClientRect(phwnd, rcClient);
MoveWindow(chwnd, rcClient->left, rcClient->top+39, rcClient->right, rcClient->bottom-39, TRUE);
HWND haddwnd = ::CreateDialogParam(hInst,
                MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1),
                phwnd,
                (DLGPROC)About,
                (LPARAM)rcClient);
ShowWindow(haddwnd, SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE);
MoveWindow(haddwnd, 0, 0, rcClient->right, 39, TRUE);
<pre>
```

Comment: I have resolve this problem, just resize the folder view window and create a new custom window and move it to the right postion, show below:

Comment: Hi @Marx. I am facing the same problem. Can you please provide me an example how you have done it? Thanks a lot!